Excel VBA (Microsoft 365): Sort of Sheets by Name is Very Slow
I am using VBA in Excel (Microsoft 365). My workbook has 50 sheets. I have a macro to sort the sheets by name, implemented as follows:
Private Sub set_speed_optimizations(enable As Boolean)
    If enable = True Then
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        Application.EnableEvents = False
    Else
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
Sub sort_sheets_by_name()
    On Error GoTo handle_error
    set_speed_optimizations True

    Dim iSheets As Integer
    iSheets = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer

    ' Sort all sheets alphabetically
    For i = 1 To iSheets - 1
        For j = i + 1 To iSheets
            If ThisWorkbook.Sheets(j).Name < ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i).Name Then
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets(j).Move Before:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i)
            End If
        Next j
    Next i

    On Error Resume Next

    ' Manually place a couple of specific sheets at the beginning of the sheets bar
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("First_0").Move Before:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("First_1").Move Before:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)

    ' Manually place a couple of specific sheets at the end of the sheets bar
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Last_N-1").Move After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(iSheets)
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Last_N").Move After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(iSheets)

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Main").Activate

    Beep

' Don't Exit Sub before this error handler because what follows needs to be
' executed in any case
handle_error:
    set_speed_optimizations False
End Sub

This macro works but runs extremely slowly. It takes ~15 minutes to order the 50 sheets by name.
The sheets are large and complex and contain workbook links to workbooks on a share (with over 170,000 references to those linked workbooks). In addition to the actions I took in set_speed_optimizations to try to speed things up, I also broke all of the workbook links.
Having done all of this, sorting the sheets alphabetically by name is still very, very slow. How may I determine what is causing this slowness and resolve it?
Edit to Add Note About Manually Moving a Single Empty Sheet
One of the sheets in my workbook is empty. If I set Formulas-->Calculation Options-->Manual and then manually drag my empty sheet one spot to the left or right on the sheets bar, Excel freezes for about 11 seconds before the sheet is moved.
Edit to Add Notes About Using O(N * lg N) Sort and Using an Array
Given my prior edit adding a note about even the manual move of a single (empty) sheet being slow and given my (small) case of N = 50, I feared the problem may not lie with use of an inefficient O(N^2) sorting algorithm. Nonetheless, I did try implementing the recommended O(N * lg N) sorting algorithm and, unfortunately, I have now demonstrated the sorting algorithm is not contributing significantly to the problem.
In addition to implementing Quicksort, I did also implement the other recommendation of storing the names in an array, sorting the array, and then using that array to move each sheet once into its proper location.
Here is my updated code:
Sub quick_sort(v_array As Variant, in_low As Long, in_high As Long)
    Dim pivot As Variant
    Dim tmp_low As Long
    Dim tmp_high As Long
    Dim tmp_swap As Variant

    tmp_low = in_low
    tmp_high = in_high

    pivot = v_array((in_low + in_high) \ 2)

    While (tmp_low <= tmp_high)
        While (v_array(tmp_low) < pivot And tmp_low < in_high)
            tmp_low = tmp_low + 1
        Wend

        While (pivot < v_array(tmp_high) And tmp_high > in_low)
            tmp_high = tmp_high - 1
        Wend

        If (tmp_low <= tmp_high) Then
            tmp_swap = v_array(tmp_low)
            v_array(tmp_low) = v_array(tmp_high)
            v_array(tmp_high) = tmp_swap
            tmp_low = tmp_low + 1
            tmp_high = tmp_high - 1
        End If
    Wend

    If (in_low < tmp_high) Then quick_sort v_array, in_low, tmp_high
    If (tmp_low < in_high) Then quick_sort v_array, tmp_low, in_high
End Sub

Private Sub set_speed_optimizations(enable As Boolean)
    If enable = True Then
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        Application.EnableEvents = False
    Else
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub

Sub sort_sheets_by_name()
    On Error GoTo handle_error
    set_speed_optimizations True

    Dim i As Long
    Dim num_sheets As Long
    Dim sheet_names()

    num_sheets = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count
    ReDim sheet_names(1 To num_sheets)

    For i = LBound(sheet_names) To UBound(sheet_names)
        sheet_names(i) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i).Name
    Next

    quick_sort sheet_names, LBound(sheet_names), UBound(sheet_names)

    Dim old_timer As Double

    For i = LBound(sheet_names) To UBound(sheet_names)
        Debug.Print sheet_names(i) & ",";
        old_timer = Timer()
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sheet_names(i)).Move After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(num_sheets)
        Debug.Print (Timer() - old_timer)
    Next

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Main").Activate

    Beep

' Don't Exit Sub before this error handler because what follows needs to be
' executed in any case
handle_error:
    set_speed_optimizations False
End Sub

Since my original post, the number of sheets I am working with has increased from N = 50 to N = 52.
I have also implemented per-sheet timings as recommended and will present a statistical summary, over all 52 sheets, of that data below. All timings have units of seconds taken to move a single sheet.




O(N^2) Sort (speed optimizations)
Quicksort (speed optimizations)
Quicksort (no speed optimizations)




MAX
13.59375
13.28515625
16.05859375


MIN
4.00390625
3.9140625
5.24609375


MEAN
12.90857873
12.72092849
14.98764273


MEDIAN
13.01953125
12.84765625
15.1875


STDDEV
1.275054623
1.249827753
1.417386677



What did surprise me was that the speed optimizations implemented in set_speed_optimizations() gave only about a 15% improvement. I say this because a quick experiment showed that moving a sheet results in recalculation (if automatic recalculation is enabled). Since my sheets are very complex, I would have thought unnecessary recalculation would be the lion's share of the problem. Apparently, it is not.
Simplifying the Problem
It might simplify the problem to focus on my earlier experiment of moving a single (empty) sheet one spot on the sheets bar. As previously stated, with automatic recalculation turned off, this takes about 11 seconds.
What might cause the move of an empty sheet one spot on the sheets bar, with automatic recalculation turned off, to take 11 seconds?

Maybe load all sheet names as strings in an array, sort that, then move the sheets? As it is you are moving a lot of sheets more than once.

Please see the addition to my original post describing the effect of putting the sheet names in an array, sorting the array, and then using that array to directly move each sheet to the spot it belongs in.

You did not implement the move counter although one simple move operation costs you 11 seconds. Therefore you cannot evaluate the savings switching to sort preparation and reducing the move operations. This is crucial.
Furthermore your comparison table does not tell about the mode of operation - I expect the first column to describe the "status ante". Your table does not disclose any significant time savings, instead of comparing apples with beans (moving sheets during each atomic sort operation) you are probably comparing beans with beans - different sort algorithms only applied to the sheet


Having done all of this, sorting the sheets alphabetically by name is still very, very slow. How may I determine what is causing this slowness and resolve it?

To determine a rough estimate for processing time use the VBA timer()-function. It returns you a counter value based on seconds.
If you insert two lines of code into your loop and initialise the variable old_timer with in front of the nested loop
DIM oldtimer as double


  If ThisWorkbook.Sheets(j).Name < ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i).Name Then
     Debug.Print timer()-oldtimer
     oldtimer=timer()
     ThisWorkbook.Sheets(j).Move Before:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i)

  End If

you will find the time for each move-operation in the output window in the VBA editor.
For some reason that I am unaware of I have to guess the sheet-move-function is pretty slow.
You should minimize those kind of operations. To track it, insert a counter for the loops:
in front of your loop:
DIM oldtimer as double
DIM movcount as long
movcount=0
within your loop:
  If ThisWorkbook.Sheets(j).Name < ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i).Name Then
               movcount=movcount+1
               Debug.Print movcount, timer()-oldtimer
               oldtimer=timer()

  ThisWorkbook.Sheets(j).Move Before:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i)

  End If

Cybernetic.nomad describes the solution in his comment!
You should only move a sheet one time.
If you divide movcount by isheets you get an idea by which factor you can improve the runtime of your specific excel sheet.
Furthermore your code implements a very slow sorting algorithm, its speed class is in the order of isheet^2, IT people say that your code is in O(n^2).
Normally the speed class only matters for big n numbers (in your case: isheet), but in your case each move-operation seems to be a heavy burden.
Hint:
Sorting data efficiently in VBA for excel without using worksheet-functions requires some programming not using fixed-length arrays but using dynamic strcutures based on vba collections. Good sorting algorithms are member in the class O(n * log(n) ). O(n * n) however, is considered as slow.

Please see the addition to my original post describing the effect of using a O(N * lg N) sorting algorithm in place of a O(N^2) sorting algorithm.

You did not implement the move counter and cannot evaluate the savings when pre-sorting the sheet names separately compared to your method.
Unfortunately you missed my ideas. Everything about sorting algorithms I wrote is located behind the word "Furthermore". I should have left that out because you missed to implement the important first hint. That is the key. My answer is primarily about execution time debugging. I would have expected you to deliver information how separately sorting affected runtime before doing anything else.

I'd be glad to assist you with optimizing the sheet sorting process in your Excel VBA code. Here are some additional considerations and potential solutions based on the information provided:
1. Sheet Structure and Complexity:

Workbook Links: While breaking workbook links can improve performance, it's essential to consider their necessity. If they're crucial for your calculations, explore alternative ways to manage them or optimize the linked formulas.
Complex Formulas and Calculations: Analyze the formulas and calculations within your sheets. If they are computationally intensive, simplify them or consider using more efficient functions or techniques.
Conditional Formatting and Data Validation: These features can significantly impact performance, especially if they involve complex rules or large datasets. Minimize their use or optimize their conditions.
Pivot Tables: Pivot tables can be slow to refresh, especially with large datasets or complex calculations. If possible, simplify their structure or consider using other data analysis methods.

2. VBA Code Optimization:

Avoid Unnecessary Loops: Minimize the number of loops and nested loops in your code. If possible, use array-based operations or built-in functions to perform calculations more efficiently.
Early Exit Conditions: If a condition is met early in a loop, use the Exit For or Exit Do statements to avoid unnecessary iterations.
Variable Declarations: Declare variables with appropriate data types to optimize memory usage and performance.
Error Handling: Use On Error GoTo sparingly and only when necessary. Excessive error handling can slow down your code.
Object References: Avoid unnecessary object references. Use Set to assign objects and release them using Set obj = Nothing when you're finished.

3. Excel Settings:

Calculation Mode: Ensure that xlCalculationManual is set in your set_speed_optimizations subroutine. This prevents unnecessary recalculations during the sorting process.
ScreenUpdating and EnableEvents: Set these properties to False to avoid visual updates and events while sorting.
Calculation Options: Explore the calculation options in Excel's settings. For example, you might consider disabling iterative calculations or adjusting precision settings if appropriate.

4. Additional Tips:

Temporary Workbook: If your workbook is extremely large or complex, consider creating a temporary workbook to perform the sorting and then copying the results back to the original workbook.
External Sorting Tools: If VBA is still too slow, explore external sorting tools or libraries that might offer better performance.

Specific Considerations for Your Case:

Manual Sheet Movement: The slowness of manually moving an empty sheet might be related to underlying calculations or linked data within the workbook, even if the sheet itself is empty. Try isolating the issue by creating a new, empty workbook and moving the sheet within it.
Array-Based Sorting: As you've already implemented, using an array-based sorting algorithm like Quicksort can be more efficient than nested loops.
Performance Profiling: Consider using a performance profiling tool to identify specific bottlenecks in your code. This can help you focus your optimization efforts on the most impactful areas.

By carefully considering these factors and implementing appropriate optimizations, you should be able to significantly improve the performance of your sheet sorting process in Excel VBA.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
